# Why was Jesse so angry at Cameron?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

[Jesse Flores](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Jesse_Flores) claimed to have gone AWOL but we learn later that she actually left the future on a personal mission to destroy the trust between John Connor and the Terminator Cameron. She also brought Riley Dawson from the future and used her to break the relationship between John & Cameron.

**How did she get back from the future if John didn't send her, and why was she so upset at the thought of John having Cameron around?**

Comment: I don’t know much about the show, but it’s possible that these sub-questions might be separate enough that they would better be asked separately (posts with multiple questions are sometimes “too broad.”)

Comment: Still, just being about one character may not be enough. Still, I’m not sure, since I don’t know much about this show. Probably you should wait for people who know a bit more about  *The Sarah Connor Chronicles* to offer their opinions.

Comment: i know about this show. because i'm watching it everyday 2T X 26D times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesse took the decision to come back from the future after it became apparent that John wasn't simply trying to *kill* all of the Terminators, he was actively engaged in two projects that she abhorred;

1) Negotiating with the Cyborg Resistance ("*Will you join us?*") and

2) using re-conditioned Terminators on the Human Resistance's bases.

When she learned that John had sent back a female-form Terminator (Cameron) to protect his younger self she realised that his fascination for Terminators may have been down to his close relationship with one in young-adulthood. She procured an attractive girl (Riley Dawson) and used her contacts with the brother of one of her unit to parlay a secret trip back into the past with the goal of turning John against Cameron.

> **Jesse:** *Not to me. There's metal everywhere these days. Looking for us.
>   Working for us. Connor's got at least one in every major base. A big
>   one flipped on us, took out half a bunker. Bird. Cullie. That's from
>   the same shrapnel that killed Cullie.*
>
> **Derek:** ***How'd you get back here?***
>
> **Jesse:** ***Cullie's brother. He's a bubble tech.***
>
> **Derek:** *He's the same one--*
>
> **Jesse:** *Who sent you back. I know.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tower is Tall but The Fall is Short](http://www.loony-archivist.com/scc/transcripts/207.htm)</sup></sub>